# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, insert, attributeerror

HELP!  Just when I get one thing working, something else doesn't work!  Again, I'm sure it's simple to experienced eyes, but I'm struggling!  This is the code where I generate my lists and the data for said lists.

```
#Frame Creation


allframes = []

for n in range (0, (workingframes*archnodes*3)):
    allframes.append(n)

frames = allframes

print frames



#Frame Population

for f in range (0, workingframes):

    if f<=(workingframes/2):

        for x in range (0, (archnodes)):
            frames[((archnodes*3)+f)].insert(((archnodes*3)+f), (archstartred[x]))
            frames[((archnodes*3)+f+workingframes)].insert(((archnodes*3)+f+workingframes),(archstartgrn[x]))
            frames[((archnodes*3)+f+workingframes*2)].insert(((archnodes*3)+f+workingframes*2),(archstartblu[x]))

        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop()
            archstartgrn.pop()
            archstartblu.pop()
            archstartred.insert(0, backred)
            archstartgrn.insert(0, backgrn)
            archstartblu.insert(0, backblu)

    else:
        for y in range (0, nodesperframe):
            archstartred.pop(0)
            archstartgrn.pop(0)
            archstartblu.pop(0)
            archstartred.append(backred)
            archstartgrn.append(backgrn)
            archstartblu.append(backblu)

        for x in range (0, (archnodes)):
            frames[(archnodes*3)+f].insert((archnodes*3), (archstartred[x]))
            frames[(archnodes*3)+f+workingframes].insert(((archnodes*3)+1),(archstartgrn[x]))
            frames[(archnodes*3)+f+workingframes*2].insert(((archnodes*3)+2),(archstartblu[x]))
```

I keep getting this lovely error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

I plan on converting the list to an array after the list is populated so that I can have it manipulated the way it needs to be.  I'm sure there's a much easier way to do this, but I don't know and I'm new to Python!

Comment: the answer by Levon is absolutely correct, but it's hard to tell what you're doing here.  Maybe if you told us what this piece of code was supposed to accomplish we could help you to fix it as opposed to telling you why you're getting a particular error.

Comment: Please note that `frames = allframes` will not make a copy, so frames and allframes refer to the same list. If you need to make a copy, use `frames = allframes[:]` or `frames = list(allframes)`.

Comment: This code is designed to populate RGB values to RGB lights.  All information is numeric, there are no text strings or data.  If the insert is causing the error, how do I populate [frames] with the other numeric data?

Comment: @SteveEdwards You have to call `insert` on the *list*, not an integer in the list - I updated my answer with some additional information about this, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These expressions `frames[((archnodes*3)+f)]` (all 3 versions) evaluate to be integers and you are trying to call an `insert()` method on them which is the cause of your error.

`f` is an integer created in the enclosing for loop, and the way `archnodes` are used in the first for loop also implies they are numbers. `frames` is a list of numbers too created in your first loop, so you are indexing into a list of numbers and then trying to call the `insert()` method on the specific number in the list. As the error message states,

`'int' object has no attribute 'insert'`

the type `int` does not have an `insert` method.

**Update** re comment above:

You can add/remove/insert items to the *list*, but you can't add/remove/insert to an integer. See this brief [tutorial/reference on lists](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm). So for instance to *insert* an item into a list you'd use this methods/approach:

```
list.insert(index, obj)
```

so in your case

```
frames.insert(index, .. )
```

not

```
frames[index].insert(..)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: "somehow evaluate to integers" -- because they're set that way in the first for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a list you need to setup the list object first, like this.

```
l = []
l.append(element)
```

If you just do the list manipulation before you do the `l = []` you will have the problem you describe.